# Boostrap Vue: mixing class names with tags

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

(Bootstrap-Vue 2.0, Vue.js 2.5)

I was wondering if it's possible to mix traditional CSS Bootstrap 4 classes with Bootstrap-Vue. For example, can I include the following?:

```
    <section id="introduction">
       <b-container class="h-100">
         <b-row class="h-100 fill-viewport align-items-center">
           <b-col cols="12">
             <h1 class="text-primary">Header text</h1>
              <p class="lead">This is my text, in a p tag</p>
           </b-col>
         </b-row>
       </b-container>
    </section>
```

with some basic CSS:

```
<style>
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
</style>
```

I'm asking this, because I'm unable to get `align-items-center` to work on a page I'm trying to create. I can get it to work with standard Bootstrap 4 using the `class=` syntax, but not with the Bootstrap-Vue tags such as `b-row` or `b-column`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The answer to this question is that **yes**, you can combine the two. Going to the Boostrap-Vue playground (from their website) and pasting the following code into the html will make this immediately obvious:

```
<b-alert show> Hello {{ name }}! </b-alert>
<button class="btn btn-primary"> WOO BLUE BUTTON </button>
<b-btn v-b-popover.hover="'I am popover content!'" title="Popover Title" class="btn btn-danger">Hover Me</b-btn>
```

My problem was, that I wasn't using the `h-100` tag for *all* the parent tags. Adding this to the `section` tag solved the problem.